# How can I make a PrimeVue TabPanel fill the available vertical space and scroll the content inside the tabs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, primevue

I've set up a sandbox to show what I'm trying to do, but essentially I want to get the content of the tabs to scroll when needed and otherwise for the tab to fill to the bottom, I'm sure the trick will be to use flex columns, but nothing i'm trying seems to work

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/primevue-demo-forked-ww2zq7?file=/src/App.vue:111,25

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

You only need to override the CSS formatting of a few PrimeVue classes, I'll show you an example using a CDN.

###### Header to left side

To add a bit of dynamism, I created a `.vertical-header` class. If you associate this with the `TabPanel`, the header will automatically become vertical on the left side.

```css
/* Header container | Content container */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* Header 1, 2, 3 */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
}

/* Header right border when not selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li:not(.p-highlight) > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* Header right border when selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li.p-highlight > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

###### Header to right side

Using the same technique, it could also be dynamically positioned on the right side (using flex-row-reverse and replacing the right border with the left border).

```
/* Content container | Header container */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* Header 1, 2, 3 */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
}

/* Header left border when not selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li:not(.p-highlight) > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* Header left border when selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li.p-highlight > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

#### Example

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const isVertical = ref(true)
    const verticalSide = ref('left') // 'left' or 'right'
    
    const toggleOrientation = () => isVertical.value = !isVertical.value
    const toggleVerticalSide = () => verticalSide.value = verticalSide.value === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'
    
    return { isVertical, verticalSide, toggleOrientation, toggleVerticalSide }
  },
  components: {
    "TabView": primevue.tabview,
    "TabPanel": primevue.tabpanel,
  },
  template: `
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <button @click="toggleOrientation">Change Vertical/Horizontal</button>
      <button @click="toggleVerticalSide">Change Left/Right</button>
    </div>
    
    <TabView :class="{
      'vertical-header-left': isVertical && verticalSide === 'left',
      'vertical-header-right': isVertical && verticalSide === 'right',
    }">
      <TabPanel header="Header 1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel header="Header 2">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel header="Header 3">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus.</p>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  `
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
/**
 ** VERTICAL HEADER TO LEFT
 *
 * .vertical-header-left
 */

/* Header container | Content container */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* Header 1, 2, 3 */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-left > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
}

/* Header right border when not selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-left > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li:not(.p-highlight) > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* Header right border when selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-left > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li.p-highlight > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/**
 ** VERTICAL HEADER TO RIGHT
 *
 * .vertical-header-right
 */
 
 /* Content container | Header container */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* Header 1, 2, 3 */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-right > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
}

/* Header left border when not selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-right > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li:not(.p-highlight) > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* Header left border when selected */
.p-tabview.p-component.vertical-header-right > .p-tabview-nav-container > .p-tabview-nav-content > .p-tabview-nav > li.p-highlight > .p-tabview-nav-link {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/core/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primevue/3.32.2/tabview/tabview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primevue/3.32.2/tabpanel/tabpanel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ok you've totally misunderstood what I'm asking which is quite possibly my fault. I am simply trying to get the tab panel to fill to the bottom of the window and for the content scroll panel to work correctly in that situation. But  also this is a vary cool modification of the panel that deserves Kudos!

Comment: Oh, oops. That was a big mistake on my part, I don't know what I was thinking. I suddenly jumped into describing my idea... Nevertheless, I'll leave it here, maybe it will be useful to someone someday... I wrote another response regarding scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

The `TabView` automatically handles the content height in PrimeVue, so you need to set the entire `TabView` container to a fixed size. After this, it's advisable to align the `nav-container` fixed to the top using CSS.

```css
/* Set TabView height */
.p-tabview.p-component {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Set Header's position to top */
.p-tabview.p-component > .p-tabview-nav-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const tabViewHeight = ref(0) // Store current height
    const updateHeight = () => {
      tabViewHeight.value = window.innerHeight // Need to save your own diagram instead
      // on your code need to use:
      /*
      // We subtract the total height occupied by the content from the window's height, and then add the currently occupied space by the tabview (since that doesn't need to be subtracted, but it's included in the pageLayout)
      tabViewHeight.value = window.innerHeight -
        document.querySelector('.pageLayout').clientHeight +
        document.querySelector('.body').clientHeight
      */
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      updateHeight() // Set first value
      window.addEventListener('resize', updateHeight) // If the window were to be changed
    })

    onUnmounted(() => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateHeight)
    })

    return { tabViewHeight }
  },
  components: {
    "TabView": primevue.tabview,
    "TabPanel": primevue.tabpanel,
  },
  template: `
    <TabView :style="{ height: tabViewHeight + 'px' }">
      <TabPanel header="Header 1">
        <p v-for="i in 200" :key="i">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel header="Header 2">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel header="Header 3">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus.</p>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  `
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
/* Set TabView height */
.p-tabview.p-component {
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Set Header's position to top */
.p-tabview.p-component > .p-tabview-nav-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/core/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primevue/3.32.2/tabview/tabview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/primevue/3.32.2/tabpanel/tabpanel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, am I right in thinking that this solution won't fill the vertical space? I'll have to set a specific height for the tab view?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. You have to predefine exactly how big it should be. If I come up with another solution, I'll modify the answer. But it's certain that you need to set the height of the tabview container correctly instead of the content.

Comment: I suppose we could add some script on window resize and have the style use a vue reactive value for height

Comment: Updated. In your code, you can calculate the height of the available space using the formula `window.innerHeight - document.querySelector('.pageLayout').clientHeight + document.querySelector('.body').clientHeight`